# Firefox turns on cookie blocking by itself

Tags: firefox, cookies

I have weird problem:

Often, when I go to joindiaspora.com, Firefox turns on blocking of cookies for that domain. It's only when I go to the front page.

I've created a video of what happens: https://blackfin.cannedtuna.org/firefox-joindiaspora-block-cookies.mp4 (4,5MB) (and uploaded to Vimeo if your don't trust the first link: https://vimeo.com/75958833)

Recently, I also experienced this on a particular subpage of flattr.com

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: are they 3rd party cookies? http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2415810,00.asp do you have any privacy software (ghostery, TACO, Disconnect, etc)

Comment: No, it's not 3rd party cookies. It is -- most importantly -- my login/session that is lost. Yes, I have some of these add-ons. I'll try disabling them and see.

Comment: Upload the video to YouTube.  its not reasonable to expect us to download a random video of unknown content.  At least if its on YouTube if it contains content that is proper it can be removed.

Comment: @Ramhound: Well, here the video is on Vimeo: https://vimeo.com/75958833 (I hope they are trustworthy in your eyes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @FrankThomas, this was caused by a privacy extension called [Priv3](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/priv3/). I installed this a long time ago, and it doesn't seem to have been updated since then. Disabling this extension, everything is working again.

I also use [Ghostery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/) to block to block trackers these days, and I think it's doing a better job.

After a bit of investigation, I found out that Priv3 blocked cookies from joindiaspora.com when a tweet was embedded, like in [this post](https://joindiaspora.com/posts/3146200). That's why I didn't have the problem all the time, but only when somebody posted a tweet in my stream. The subpage on Flattr suffering from this issue also contains an embedded tweet.